# Firebase cloud function is still public after appcheck enforced

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-app-check

I have a Flutter mobile app (no web). I want the `getData` function to be accessed by my app only. When I did not have any app check the function was accessible through any web browser because it was public.

After I enable appcheck and add the following code. The app cloud function is still accessible like before publically.

How do I fix this?

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp();


exports.getData = functions
    .runWith({
        enforceAppCheck: true, 
    })
    .https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of writing, [Firebase App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check) can be used with:

> App Check currently works with the following Firebase products:
>
> - Realtime Database
> - Cloud Firestore
> - Cloud Storage
> - Cloud Functions (callable functions)
> - Authentication (beta; requires upgrade to Firebase Authentication with Identity Platform)

In your code, you define a [HTTPS Request Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?gen=1st), which is not a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=1st).

To use App Check, you will need to [redefine your function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/cloud-functions) as a Callable Cloud Function:

```js
exports.getData = functions
    .runWith({
        enforceAppCheck: true, 
    })
    .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
        return { /* ... response data ... */ }; 
    });
```

Then on your client, you would [call it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=1st#dart) using:

```dart
try {
  final result =
      await FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('addMessage').call();
  // do something with result
} on FirebaseFunctionsException catch (error) {
  print(error.code);
  print(error.details);
  print(error.message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @samthecodingman's answer, you can also use a normal
`https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {` but then you'd have to manually check the app check token from the header.

So the flow would be like this

1. you obtain the app check token on your client
2. you make a request to your function and add the `X-Firebase-AppCheck` header with the obtained value
3. in your cloud function you check the header's token validity `await getAppCheck().verifyToken(appCheckToken);`